# Can a chrome extension white-list third-party cookies/storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a Chrome extension that injects an iframe from foo.com into bar.com. So, now bar.com contains a foo.com iframe. This iframe tries to write to localStorage, but I noticed that it will fail if the user has "Ignore exceptions and block third-party cookies from being set" checked. Is there any way the extension can add a domain to a white list to be exempted from this?

Comment: According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) `localStorage` is the same as `globalStorage[location.hostname]` so wouldn't any attempt to write to it from the iframe only apply to the `localStorage` for foo.com?

Comment: Alasdair, I might be misunderstanding you. But I want the foo.com iframe to have its own localStorage.  It's localStorage data should be isolated from barr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried myself, but it might be possible with [`chrome.experimental.contentSettings`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.contentSettings.html#type-ContentSetting) API.